How to determine outliers based on a regression logarithmic-scaled?
I'm facing a problem were I'd like to detect outliers from a data collection. The goal is to be able to identify outliers from a variable Y based on its relation with the variable X.
To do that, I did:

A plot in logarithmic scale

A regression between the two variables with the following function  def exponential_function(x, a, b): return b * (x ** a). In this way, variable Y has an theorical estimation based on variable X.

I calculated the residuals with the logarithmic values and normalized them in order to determine the outlier. I considered that further the datapoint is from its estimation, the most likely is to be considered an outlier.


For the moment, I just decided that only the 5% of normalized residuals are considered outliers -95th percentile- (you can see them in the picture as red).
My questions are:
**1. What are the most common methods to detect outliers from regressions
log-based?

Is there any other robust method to determine what are the outliers which is not based on the amount of datapoints? - this is, not based on percentiles. E.g. If my sample only contains 100 datapoints, but they are all "close to the estiation", I don't want the code to force that there are 5 outliers due to the 95th percentile, but to tell me that there's no outlier detected since they are all reasonable and close to the estimation.**

Thank you in advance!
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/BHQZOKLz.png

Why we want to do this. If we have assumed a linear relation, then create a 3rd variable which is basically the ratio i.e. Y/X and then find outliers for the 3rd variable using typical methods e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22357811/2187625

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
